# How do I repeatedly write to a file?

Tags: files-and-directories

I can use the code snippet below to write the numbers to a file (here on the os x desktop), but when I delete the file (using Finder) and rerun, I get an empty file. Quitting Wolfram Desktop and restarting restores the write, but, again, only once.

```
doFileTest[] := (
  trainedGuesses := {0.9986710548400879`, 0.9999996423721313`, 
    0.9999927282333374`, 0.0017948150634765625`, 
    0.0027101843152195215`, 0.002895207144320011`, 
    0.9999996423721313`, 0.001447718241252005`, 
    0.000766970042604953`} ;
  trainedGuessesFile := 
   CreateFile[ File[ "~/Desktop/TrainedGuesses.txt" ] ] ;
  WriteString[ trainedGuessesFile , trainedGuesses ] ;
  ) ;

doFileTest[]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My hint: Use `=` instead of `:=`. This is Mathematica, not Maple nor Pascal. Make sure you know the difference. Here, the `:=` (`SetDelayed`) causes the file to be created each time you call `trainedGuessesFile`. Starting with the second call, this causes trouble because the file already exists.

Here a more structured approach:

```
trainedGuesses = {0.9986710548400879`, 0.9999996423721313`, 
   0.9999927282333374`, 0.0017948150634765625`, 
   0.0027101843152195215`, 0.002895207144320011`, 0.9999996423721313`,
    0.001447718241252005`, 0.000766970042604953`};

stream = OpenWrite["~/Desktop/TrainedGuesses.txt"];
WriteString[stream, "Data = "];
WriteLine[stream, trainedGuesses];
WriteLine[stream, "döp"];
WriteLine[stream, "döp"];
WriteLine[stream, "döp"];
WriteLine[stream, "dö-dö"];
WriteLine[stream, "döpp"];
WriteLine[stream, "döpp"];
WriteLine[stream, "döpp"];
Close[stream]
```

Never forget to `Close` an open stream. Otherwise you will run into similar trouble as before.

Comment: Perhaps also see [`OpenAppend`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/OpenAppend.html)